# problem while updating backbox using sudo apt-get update

Tags: git, sql

```
[*] starting at 19:46:20

[19:46:20] [INFO] updating sqlmap to the latest development version from the GitHub repository
[19:46:20] [INFO] update in progress ..
[19:46:22] [ERROR] update could not be completed ('From git github com sqlmapproject sqlmap branch HEAD FETCH_HEAD error Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge udf postgresql linux 32 8 3 lib_postgresqludf_sys so udf postgresql linux 32 8 4 lib_postgresqludf_sys so udf postgresql linux 32 9 0 lib_postgresqludf_sys so udf postgresql linux 64 8 2 lib_postgresqludf_sys so udf postgresql linux 64 8 3 lib_postgresqludf_sys so udf postgresql linux 64 8 4 lib_postgresqludf_sys so udf postgresql linux 64 9 0 lib_postgresqludf_sys so Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge Aborting')
[19:46:22] [INFO] for Linux platform it's required to install a standard 'git' package (e.g.: 'sudo apt-get install git')

[*] shutting down at 19:46:22
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [GH issue](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/issues/541), you should run the following commands:

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap.git sqlmap
cd sqlmap
python sqlmap.py --update
```

Prefix `python` command with `sudo` if necessary.